# React + Typescript + RefForward with children: Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Props>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Someone help me fix this typescript's error. I can't do it after hours of searching. This is the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xzmxo7?file=pages%2Findex.tsx

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Props>'.
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Props>'.
Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
Type 'HTMLDivElement' has no properties in common with type 'Props'.(2322)
index.d.ts(133, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLDivElement & RefAttributes<Props>'
```

Comment: here is an [example](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#forwardrefcreateref) and type order is reversed in forwardedRef